# Eclipse History view blank

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control

After updating to Eclipse 4.5 Mars the History view always remains blank, no matter if I drag a file from the Eclipse Navigator or select Team >> Show History from the context menu. I'm using both Git and CVS - the problem is the same.

[image]

I found this entry in the .log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-07-03 10:09:28.308
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4187)
    at org.eclipse.team.ui.TeamUI.showHistoryFor(TeamUI.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.ShowResourceInHistoryAction$1.run(ShowResourceInHistoryAction.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.repo.RepositoryManager.run(RepositoryManager.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction$2.run(CVSAction.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction$3.run(CVSAction.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction.run(CVSAction.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.ShowResourceInHistoryAction.execute(ShowResourceInHistoryAction.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.actions.CVSAction.run(CVSAction.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.TeamAction.runWithEvent(TeamAction.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Works fine for me on 4.5 using SVN. I don't see any obvious bug reports (but there are a lot of History View bugs).

Comment: Does resizing the view help?

Comment: Nope... Neither maximizing nor moving the view helps

Comment: This looks like it's using CVS and falling over. Are any of the projects in your workspace shared using CVS? Try closing all other projects except the one you're testing, and then right-click and do 'show in synchronizing view' to see if it recognises the repository type.

Comment: I'm using the Team synchronizing perspective without any problem. It does not seem to be a CVS problem.
I opened a bug ticket with eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471782

Answer (score 22):

It appears to be a bug in Eclipse. These bug reports reference it:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467714
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471782

The second one had a way to reset your perspectives to get it working again vs adding the history view manually. It worked for me with Mars.1

(comment from neil mordecai)

1. Close all perspectives. (Window > Perspective > Close All Perspective)
2. Restart eclipse (shows only default JavaEE perspective) - add Java if you like...
3. Using Package Explorer, select file and VIA SpeedBar (rh-mouse-button-select) use Team > Show History.

Once opened in this way the History remains synchronised indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks David. This bug report (471782) has been submitted by me. So I'm currently following it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. At first I was manually closing the perspectives  and it wasn't working but once I selected the Close all perspectives option under Window > Perspective  and restarted eclipse it's working correctly again.